# Randomly select x % times

Tags: r

In R, I want to apply condition based on selection of N% times within loop.

```
 for(i in 1:120) {
   if (randomly select 3% times of 120 iterations) { 
   print(i)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the [sample](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sample) function:

```r
for(i in 1:120) {
  if(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1, prob = c(0.03, 0.97))) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

The function samples from `TRUE` and `FALSE` with the probability of 3% and 97% respectively. Depending on what you'd like to do with those `i`s, there might be solutions that do not even involve a for loop.

Comment: 120*3% = 3.6. It should return 3 values. It is returning 2 sometimes

Comment: I see! Why not removing the for loop entirely: `sample(1:120, size = floor(120*0.03))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Print `i` if `i` is equal to a random percent of the total iterations? `sample(1:120, size = 1)` will randomly select one number from 1 to 120, which will represent a random percentage of the total iterations

```r
for(i in 1:120) {
  if (i == sample(1:120, size = 1)) { 
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: How to define 3% random selection here?